# Creating a directory and a user, then giving permission of this created directory for the created user

Tags: shell-script, shell

I want to learn shell scripting and i need your help.

**Problem:** My Script should create first a directory of X then a user, if the user doesn't exist, it creates a user with full read and write permission to the created directory of X.
I don't know, where is my mistake.

**My Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please create a directory Name! "
read dn
cd
mkdir /home/$dn
ls /home


echo write the user Name!
read usrnm

if [ `sed -n "/^$usrnm/p" /etc/passwd` ]
then
    echo "the user $usernm" exists already
else
    useradd -M $usernm
    chown -R $usernm /home/$dn
    chmod -R u+rX /home/$dn
    echo $usernm is being successfully created!
    #cat /etc/group
fi
```

Thanks a lot for your kindly feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a lot of issues with the script:

Line 5, `mkdir /home/$dn` - can lead to all sorts of funky things if the user enters something with a space inside, replace it with `mkdir "/home/$dn"`.

Line 9, `echo write the user Name!` is bad. The "!" character has a special meaning in bash, so I'd avoid using it as is even in a script. Again, please add quotes, e.g. `echo 'write the user Name!'`

In line 10 you read `usrnm` and then later you use it without double quotes which is really bad and also in line 16 you use a **different** variable `usernm`.

I've replaced your sed command with something more manageable and simple.

Here's your fixed script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please create a directory Name! "
read dn
cd
mkdir "/home/$dn"
ls /home

echo 'write the user Name!'
read usrnm

if grep -qw "$usrnm" /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null
then
    echo "the user $usernm" exists already
else
    useradd -M "$usrnm"
    chown -R "$usrnm" "/home/$dn"
    chmod -R u+rX "/home/$dn"
    echo $usrnm is being successfully created!
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! could you explain a bit your if statement whole sentence, please?

Comment: As for grep: `-q` means don't produce any output; `-w` means search for a whole word, e.g. it won't match `abc` in `abcd`; `2>/dev/null` means redirect errors to `/dev/null` to make the script work prettier.

Comment: sorry, i can not up vote your answer :(, says, i am new here